# Website not responsive in mobile but in computer

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have created a responsive website with **Bootstrap 3**. While I have tested it in Mozilla and Chrome on my computer, it is responsive. But on a phone (Samsung S Duos 2) it's home page is responsive, but not other pages. On the home page it shows responsive dropdown nav menu and all. But for other pages it shows the ordinary navigation menu like computer. I don't know why this is happening.

For bootstrap menu I've styled only for screen size greater than 768px (using a media query `@media(min-height:768px)`)

I am sharing the website link [here](http://www.testing15.cybrolab.info) please anyone help me to sort it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply your meta tag of your homepage to your another pages

Comment: thats the issue, now wroks fine , thanx :-)